# Failed to find GoogleReminderOverride, GoogleEventAttendee and GoogleReminder in salesforce

Tags: json

I started learning JSON Generator in salesforce. While researching about JSONGenerators, I found following link

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_Apex_JSON

Where i seen these **GoogleReminderOverride, GoogleEventAttendee and GoogleReminder**.

i can't understand what these are whether these are classes or any standard object/custom objects.

If these are classes, then what type of classes these are?

if these are object, what are the fields does these contains?

If any one know about these **GoogleReminderOverride, GoogleEventAttendee and GoogleReminder**, please suggest me.

I am not able to go forward to learn about JSON Generators.
Thanking you

Comment: Those are classes from demo application

Comment: OKay @Kurunve, Can you provide full sample code for those classes???

Comment: The demo application you linked to on the Developer site includes a link for the unmanaged package for it https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04td0000000E47S